# 专心 VS 专注 VS 关注, with 于 in the mix

Tags: mandarin

I'm struggling with a couple things...first is the ability to know when is the right time to use each of the above, each which seems to more or less mean "to concentrate on".

*I think* 关注 has the meaning more of like, following the news, updates, or something.

And I think 专心 is to concentrate in general, whereas 专注 might be to concentrate at the exclusion of other things... but I have no clue. And I'm struggling to figure out when you need 于 afterwards, and when you don't.

Comment: as if this could not be settled by looking up dictionaries:https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E4%B8%93%E5%BF%83 https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E4%B8%93%E6%B3%A8 https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E5%85%B3%E6%B3%A8 （１００ sample sentences for each at jukuu) http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%93%E5%BF%83 http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%93%E6%B3%A8 http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%85%B3%E6%B3%A8

Comment: I didn't know about jukuu! That said, I did look things up in a dictionary and wasn't able to get a good enough sense of the difference. I appreciate your suggestion, don't appreciate the snark. Why even bother typing it out? A little rush on the internet? Taking up precious stackexchange space? Grow up.

Answer (score 3):

- `关注` has different meaning with `专心` and `专注`. `关注` doesn't mean `to
  concentrate`. Usually `关注` means `to care about` or `to pay attention
  to sth`.
- `专心` and `专注` are very similar. They can be alternative to each other most of the time, although there are some collocations you can only use one of them.
- As for `于`, it is a preposition, same as `on` here. If you use `专心` or `专注` as a verb (usually a intransitive verb), then you may need it.
- Though `专心/注` can be verb, they are often used as adverb too. In such case, no more `于`.
- The (little) difference between `专心/注`:

  - `专心` is used more often to describe one's inner condition, while `专注` is used for one's appearance, look or expression.

Comment: Would be helpful if the answer actually included what is the small dissimilarity between 专心 and 专注

Comment: @MariaEfremova Thanks for the advice. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

> 专 = exclusive/concentrate
>
> 心 = heart/mind
>
> **专心** = **concentrate** (of mind set) *
>
> - *not concern about anything else*
>
> Example: 专心读书 (concentrate on study); 专心工作 (concentrate on work)

~

> 专 = exclusive/concentrate
>
> 注 = pay attention
>
> **专注** = **concentrate** (of attention)  / pay full attention
>
> - *pay no attention to anything else*
>
> Example: 专注读书 (pay full attention to one's study); 专注工作 (pay full attention to one's work)

~

> **关注** = 关心 (concern) +  注视 (pay attention to) = **pay serious attention**

于 is a preposition(on; at; to) before the object. It is better be omitted from phrases like 专心(于)读书 or 专注(于)工作 to make it less wordy.

Comment: This is great! To clarify, are there any cases where 于 must be present? Or where having it is incorrect grammatically (vs being wordy)? Thanks again

Comment: The question should be " When can we omit 于?" -- 专心**于**读书 (concentrate **on** study) or 专注**于**工作  (concentrate **on** work) is grammatically correct, but omitting the preposition 于(on) does not change the context. We can omit the preposition if is clearly implied . For example: "I work hard on writing my novel" and "I work hard writing my novel" mean the same thing.

Comment: I meant if you need a preposition to connect a verb and a noun, or an adverb and verb, you should has it in place first, and then see if you can omit it. For example, if you omit the 于 in  沉醉于工作 (immerse in work) the meaning of the phrase would become unclear, - 沉醉工作 could mean "he is deeply drunk  while he works."

Comment: I see -- very helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

It depend where you use the word:

专心 ----> a general qualification about concentrate, can used in housework, in watching film, walking on the road etc etc.

专注 ---> we talk on a project, a work, or sth need to spend lots of mindwork.

Hope you understand the subtle diffr.

the farther one is: 关注 ---> it's a bit formal word, used more or less in the reportage in news or some charitable activities, eg. we 关注 the degradation of the environement, the famine in some poor area; or eg. The mayor 关注 on the event of the traffic accident/strike.